# JFileChooser on MacOS: How is the localization of the names of special folders like 'Desktop' determined?

Tags: java, swing, installation, install4j

I have a situation where the special folder names on MacOS are French, but the labels & buttons are German (the OS language is English):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On Windows the special folder names are determined by the the system language.

On MacOS, they are determined by the key `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` in `Info.plist`.

By default, install4j sets this key to the value of the installer "principal language":

[image]

The writing of this settings can be disabled by setting the compiler variable `sys.ext.setDevelopmentRegion` to false. If this key does not exist, the names are localized according to the MacOS system language (like on Windows).

The value can also be customized on a per launcher basis by adding a custom Info.plist-fragment:

[image]